# How to remove last child of body in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i want to remove a last div of body as highlighted in image. I have tried with jqyery `$('body :last-child').remove()` but this deletes everything between the body tag. I have also tried with

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   body.removeChild(body.lastChild);
```

this also doesnot work for me. 
[image]

How can i delete this div?

Comment: It would be better if you can post the html over here instead of using an image

Comment: if you are using jquery, see this https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: "remove a last div of body": `$('body').children('div').last().remove();`

Comment: The problem with `lastChild` is that it takes white space text nodes into account. If you want the vanilla version, you can go with sth. like `document.body.removeChild(document.body.children[document.body.children.length-1]);` ... `children` only contains _element_ children, so that works in this situation. But if you're using jQuery already, some of the existing answers are probably more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('body').children('div').last()` to select last child div of body tag.

You can implement like following.

```js
$('body').children('div').last().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The div element i want to delete lies below the script tag, does this affect the deletion of element? . As i applied your code, the div element above the script tag is deleted [all the scripts are inside body tag].

Comment: @SurajKhanal it doesnt affect the deletion this code makes last div element of body deleted.

Comment: It is working now. My mistake, i am executing code without document ready. And thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.last()` in `jquery` to select the last div, and then use `empty()` to remove from the div.

```js
$('body div').last().empty()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector needs to specify that you are looking at children elements of the body.

```
$('body>:last-child').remove()
```

Comment: doing this deletes the div element  immediate children of body

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  I'm glad you got it working from hsnbl's answer, but although these answers work for you now, you should look into a different way to get rid of this element.  If you are able to put an id attribute on it, or a class, you would be much better off.

Comment: This div is watermark of host and dynamically attached to my site, i am unable to attach any id and class to it. Your code seems to work for me well. I just forgot to write code with document ready function. And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the last child of a `body` tag, not any `body` tag that is a last child. Try this:

```
$('body > :last-child').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$('body').find('div:last-child').remove();
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/AdamMichalski/dr1pmLp0/1/)